# Alphabetic pagination classic ASP vbscript

Tags: javascript, html, sql-server, vbscript, asp-classic

How would I send a hidden input values through `HTML` post. I would prefer to do this without `JavaScript` as I don't know it to well but if that is the only way how would you post it with JavaScript? I could pass the values and get them with `QueryString` but I prefer not to.

Code:

```
alphaChar = request.Form("alpha")
if alphaChar <>"" then
    Response.Write alphaChar
    response.Write("Test")
end if


                <a href="<%=obj_Session.str_FileName%>">#</a>
                <% for i = 97 to 122 %> <a href="<%=obj_Content.GetContent("PageName")%>">
                <input type="hidden" name="alpha" value="<%=CHR(i)%>">
                <%=CHR(i)%></a>&nbsp;<%
                next
                %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution in which i can use post with hyperlinks. I used css to style buttons as hyperlinks and send values through post. Code below.

```
 <form action="Table.asp" method="post" name="form2">
<input type="submit" name="Button" value="#" style="background:transparent;border:0;display:inline;color:#00F;text-decoration:underline;padding:0px">
<% for i = 97 to 122 %> 

     <input type="submit" name="Button" value="<%=CHR(i) %>" style="background:transparent;border:0;display:inline;color:#00F;text-decoration:underline;padding:0px">&nbsp;
     <% next %>

 </br></br></br>

 <%
    alphaB = request.form("Button")
 if alphaB <>"" then
        response.write alphaB
 end if

%>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using Request.Form on the server side. is this a must?

alternativley you could use just links and make a href on your asp page e.g. test.asp?char=A or test.asp?char=#

then on the serverdside use request.querystring("char")

Comment: I already know how to do it via querystring but im looking for a way to pass it through post method if possible even if i can only do it with javascript